# Function of two independent random variable dependent or independent?

Tags: probability

If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are three independent random variable, and $A = X + Y$ and $B = Y + Z$ are $A$ and $B$ dependent?

Comment: What kind of random vars?

Comment: which ones? A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not independent, they both have $Y$ component but to ensure this, a simple test can help us, calculating cross covariance (I assume all variables are real for simplicity) $\mathbb{E}\left[(A-\mathbb{E}(A))(B-\mathbb{E}(B))\right]$, where $\mathbb{E}(A)=\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(B) = \mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(Z)$, therefore

$$\mathbb{E}\left[(A-\mathbb{E}(A))(B-\mathbb{E}(B))\right]=\mathbb{E}(AB)-\mathbb{E}(A)\mathbb{E}(B)\\ =\mathbb{E}((X+Y)(Y+Z))-\mathbb{E}(X+Y)\mathbb{E}(Y+Z)\\ 
=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Z)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)+\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Z)\\-\left(\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Z)+\mathbb{E}(Y)^2+\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Z)\right) \\ = \mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2
$$

If $A,B$ are independent, then their cross covariance must be equal to zero in general (that's a necessary condition but not sufficient), but we see that their cross covariance is equal to variance of $Y$ which is not zero in general, thus they are not independent.

Comment: So it is incorrect to write $\Pr(A>a \cap B>b) = \Pr(A>a) * \Pr(B>b)$?

Comment: No it is not, they are dependent. Check solution above carefully.

Comment: $\Pr(A>a,B>b) = \int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_{b-Z}^\infty \int\limits_{a-Y}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z) dxdydz$. Will this be correct then?

Comment: $F_{A,B}(a,b)=\text{Pr}(A\le a,B\le b)=\text{Pr}(X+Y\le a,Y+Z\le b)=\text{Pr}(X\le a-Y,Z\le b-Y) \\ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}f_Y(y)f_X(x)dxdy\times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{b-y}f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dzdy$

Comment: $\text{Pr}(X\le a-Y,Z\le b-Y) \\ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}f_Y(y)f_X(x)dxdy\times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{b-y}f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dzdy = \Pr(X\le a-Y)\times\Pr(Z\le b-Y)$. This is because X and Z are independent, right?

Comment: Yes because $X,Z$ are independent and $A,B$ are independent on the condition that we know $Y$ and the outer integral is for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=0=Z$ and $Y$ any non-constant random variable. Then $X,Y,Z$ are independent but $A=B=Y$ and $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

An example where $A$ and $B$ are independent is obtained by taking $X=Y=Z=0$, so nothing can be said about independence of $A$ and $B$ in general.